# C++ return value from multithreads using reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, return-value

Here is my code:

```
vector<MyClass> objs;
objs.resize(4);

vector<thread> multi_threads;
multi_threads.resize(4);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    multi_threads[i] = std::thread(&MyFunction, &objs[i]);  
                   // each thread change some member variable in objs[i]
    multi_threads[i].join();
}
```

I expect that the elements in `objs` can be changed at each thread. Then after the threads finished, I can get access to the member data.

However, when the program finished the above loop, the member variables I'd like to get is not changed at all.

I guess this is because the multi-threading mechanism in C++, but I don't know what exactly I did wrong. And may I know how to achieve my expectation?

Many thanks.

=================================================================================
EDIT:

Here is the source code of `MyFunc`:

```
void MyFunc(MyClass &obj)
{
    vector<thread> myf_threads;
    myf_threads.resize(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myf_threads[i] = std::thread(&AnotherClass::increaseData, &obj);
        myf_threads[i].join();
    }
 }
```

And here is `AnotherClass::increaseData`:

```
void AnotherClass::increaseData(Myclass& obj)
{
    obj.add();
}

void MyClass::add()
{
    data++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`objs` is empty when first accessed, causing undefined behaviour:

```
multi_threads[i] = std::thread(&MyFunction, &objs[i]);
                                           //^^ 'objs' is empty, so this access
                                           // is out-of-bounds.
```

There must be instances of `MyClass` within `objs` before accessing it. Avoid potential reallocation of the internal buffer used by the `objs` `vector` by allocating the required number of elements upfront. If reallocation occurs previous pointers acquired would be dangling:

```
std::vector<MyClass> objs(4);
std::vector<std::thread> multi_threads(objs.size());
```

To avoid sequential execution of the threads `join()` with the threads in a subsequent loop instead of in the creation loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    multi_threads[i] = std::thread(&MyFunction, &objs[i]);
}

for (auto& t: multi_threads) t.join();
```

See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=af425576fbf3143f13ab1535aa4f1421-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

---

After the update, it appears the function being used for the thread is taking a *reference*, not a pointer, to a `MyClass` instance (even though a pointer is being passed to the `std::thread` constructor?). In this case, [`std::ref(objs[i])`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) must be used to avoid *copying* of the `MyClass` instance by the `std::thread` constructor (see [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=46ae093400757d19c7c90df2a7086592-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)). Note from the [`std::thread::thread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) reference page:

> The arguments to the thread function are copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a mistyping. Please check my update. Many thanks.

Comment: @UserLong, can you post the definition of `MyFunction` ? Or better, a small compilable program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi, hmjd. I've post the code of MyFunc. Please have a look. Many thanks.

Comment: @UserLong, but the `std::thread` constructor is taking a `MyClass*` and the function that is posted is taking a `MyClass&`? If it really is a `MyClass&` then use `std::ref(objs[i])` to pass the argument otherwise a copy will be made by the `std::thread` constructor and means the function will be modifing a _copy_ of an object from `objs`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
std::ref(objs[i])
```

helps you.
I had the same problem with referenced parameters in the function for the thread
and that helped me.